# Can I use a campy (Campagnolo) 11 speed chain on a Sram Force 22 drivetrain?

Tags: chain, compatibility, drivetrain, sram, campagnolo

After reading [this article](https://cyclingtips.com/2019/12/the-best-bicycle-chain-durability-and-efficiency-tested/) about “finding the best bicycle chain”. The article goes through factors like chain endurance and power transfer efficiency. After reading the article I see that the Campagnolo Record 11 speed chain looks considerably good at a competitive price point.

I know that the Sram 22 red chain width is [5.6mm while the Campy chain width is 5.5mm](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=164161).

So considering all above and that a Sram Red 22 is compatible with Force 22 drive train.

Is it safe to assume that a Campagnolo Record 11 speed will also be compatible?

If it’s not a given, how can I test compatibility after I purchase the chain?

Comment: [Cycling Tips](https://cyclingtips.com) sure seems like a site meant to promote its advertiser's products.  Every single lubricant tested in the [chain lube article](https://cyclingtips.com/2018/03/fast-chain-lube-that-saves-you-money/) is an expensive boutique "bicycle" lube.  I'd pay attention to them if they would test against something like a DuPont PTFE-based lube that you can buy by the liter for less money than the "soooper speshul bicycle lube that makes you faster" lubes they're pushing and that are really nothing more than something like that DuPont lube bought in bulk and repackaged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

11 speed road was a singular moment of convergence where all the chains are close enough to exactly the same width that they can interchange in a pinch and the bike will go without major issue. It's the only generation like that completely across the board since 5/6 speed chains.

Between Shimano, SRAM, and Campy (all the companies that make matching chains and cassettes), you basically always get the best shifting performance by matching the chain brand with the cassette. The ramp profiling is designed to match precisely and it's hard to beat that. Yes Campy chains are excellent and have good wear life, so if wear life by itself is all you're after, go for it.

Comment: If the idea is that the chain width determines compatibility, it should be noted that Campagnolo had two different widths for 10 speed chains.